# Can Java Web Start install a Windows driver, and also copy dll and jar into the Java dirs?

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-web-start, rxtx

My Java FX2 application configures a serial device and as part of deployment, it has to install a Windows device driver and also copy native libs (RxTx serial port libs) over into the Java dirs.

Can Java Web Start handle it? Or should user do it in stages: install driver manually, then copy over libs, then install application via Web Start.

---

**Update:**
MyApp.jar below is self-signed. I put the dll under the project name. I added this line for the dll in my jnlp. I am using Netbeans 7.3 and so put the VM args line.
My jnlp looks like this:

```
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Djava.library.path=. "  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="MyApp.jar" size="216992" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/RXTXcomm.jar" size="66493" download="eager" />
    <nativelib  href="rxtxSerial.dll" size="122880" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

I can run the app in the Netbeans IDE. However, clicking the jnlp, I get the popup, 'Runtime Error'. It asks me to click for details, but there's nothing shown.
I deleted earlier jnlps in the Temporary Internet Files in Java Control Panel. In the Java console I see nothing.

@AndrewThompson I tried Janela to check the jnlp. Useful tool! I see that the dll did not make it into the dist folder. The jnlp is generated by NB 7.3. Is there any way to get it to put in the line for nativelib? I have to do it manually each time.
`

> JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17
>
> Report for
>   file:/D:/Profiles/Anil/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/MyApp.jnlp
>
> Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of
>   application/x-java-jnlp-file cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
>   was found starting with element 'jfx:javafx-runtime'. One of '{java,
>   j2se, jar, nativelib, extension, property, package}' is expected.
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'jfx:javafx-runtime'. One of '{java, j2se, jar, nativelib,
>   extension, property, package}' is expected. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:
>   Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of
>   '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc,
>   installer-desc}' is expected. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
>   was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources,
>   application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is
>   expected. XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8 Codebase not
>   specified.  Defaulting to
>   file:/D:/Profiles/Anil/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/ The
>   resource download at MyApp.jar can be optimized by removing the
>   (default) value of download='eager'. The resource download at
>   MyApp.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of
>   main='false'. It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the
>   app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the MyApp.jar resource. Lazy
>   downloads might not work as expected for MyApp.jar unless the download
>   'part' is specified.  Resource 'lib/RXTXcomm.jar' declared as size
>   '66490' but is actually '66512'. The resource download at
>   lib/RXTXcomm.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of
>   download='eager'. The resource download at lib/RXTXcomm.jar can be
>   optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'. It might be
>   possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying
>   download='lazy' for the lib/RXTXcomm.jar resource. Lazy downloads
>   might not work as expected for lib/RXTXcomm.jar unless the download
>   'part' is specified.  Problem fetching resource rxtxSerial.dll. 
>   D:\Profiles\Anil\My
>   Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\dist\rxtxSerial.dll (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)
>   `

I put the dll into a jar, and added
`System.loadLibrary("./rxtxSerial");`
That too failed.

Comment: JWS offers an [extension installer service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).  *"..to identify an installer/uninstaller for an application. The intent of the installer is to do any application set-up/pull-down that can not be handled by the standard JWS behaviour of caching the classes/resources at 1st launch, and clearing them at uninstall."*

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the demo. I looked at the code. I can see how I would copy over the dlls using the service.

Comment: *"I can see how I would copy over the dlls using the service."*  To be honest I just skimmed the question.  But no need for an installer for DLLs, just put them in the root of a signed Jar, and add them to the run-time class-path as a `nativelib` element.  Obviously, partition them for each OS.

Comment: @AndrewThompson However I am unsure of how to do the device driver install through JWS. Perhaps it should *not* be done through JWS?

Comment: What exactly is the 'device driver'? Is it a native?  A class in a Jar?

Comment: @AndrewThompson  Also separately, http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_for_Windows says that "Copy rxtxserial.dll to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
Copy rxtxcomm.jar to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext". The device driver is a .inf file.

Comment: Sun/Oracle has been advising for ***years*** not to put DLLs into the directories of the JRE.  Just put them in the root of a Jar like I advised, and try it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This person had to jump through a lot of hoops to do it http://mailman.qbang.org/pipermail/rxtx/2010-September/12297485.html

Comment: Wow!  You spent 2 days looking up that thread rather than 4 hours trying it yourself?  That person is/was very naive.  The answer is hinted in *"Use of native libraries require unrestricted acces to the system."* - besides being digitally signed, the JNLP ***must explicitly request extended privileges.***  That was mentioned in the first reply.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Does the rxtxcom.jar need to have its certificates deleted and then re-signed and with each library having a separate jnlp? http://mailman.qbang.org/pipermail/rxtx/2010-September/12297491.html

Comment: Stop reading that bloody thread.  It is mostly 'the blind leading the blind'.  Try some things, experiment.  If you come up with a specific question, ask it as an edit.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the suggestions. I did it and have posted the error.

Comment: Validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson that didn't work - I have listed as an answer, what worked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you remain in the sandbox (unsigned app) you won't access to the local file system. Regarding the device driver installation i suppose a signed app could do it too, but it will probably trigger Windows confirmation.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html

Answer (score 0):

What worked was this

> Using a simpler approach (confirmed to work when using NetBeans or
>   Borland JBuilder):
>
> Add RXTXcomm.jar as a library
>
> compile (build) your application
>
> **add the rxtxSerial.dll to the root of the distribution folder
>   (*projectname*/dist when using NetBeans)**

from the wiki http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Deploying_JAVA_with_RXTX

The advice (from Andrew) to put a 'nativelib' directive in the jnlp, did not work.